# PyQt 4: Get Position of Toolbar

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt4

Hy guys,

in my executable program there is a toolbar. Well, the user decides to move the toolbar. Now the toolbar is floating. I know I have to conntect the floating-signals that is emittted when the toolbar ist arranged by the user. How can I save the new position of the toolbar? I know the method of adding the toolbar to the main window with a position:`self.addToolBar( Qt.LeftToolBarArea , toolbar_name)`. In the handle_floating()-method you see what I want: There I want to get the position currently, but how? You also see I have just added one member variable, named `self.toolbar_pos`, to hold the position of the toolbar. My idea is, when application is terminated I want to serialize this value to a file, and later, when application is ran again its will read that file and set the toolbar accordingly. But this is no problem. Currently I don't have no idea to get the position of the toolbar.

I need your help :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.toolbar_pos = None

        self.initUI()      

    def initUI(self):               

        exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)

        self.toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar(self)
        self.toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar )
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        self.toolbar.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea
                                     | QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea
                                     | QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea
                                     | QtCore.Qt.RightToolBarArea)

        self.addToolBar( QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea , self.toolbar )

        self.toolbar.topLevelChanged.connect(self.handle_floating)


    def handle_floating(self, event):
        #   The topLevel parameter is true
        #   if the toolbar is now floating
        if not event:
            #   If the toolbar no longer floats,
            #   then calculate the position where the
            #   toolbar is located currently.
            self.toolbar_pos = None
            print "Get position: ?"



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Toolbar example')    
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QMainWindow` class already has APIs for this: i.e. [saveState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#saveState) and [restoreState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#restoreState). These can be used to save and restore the state of all the toolbars and dock-widgets in your application.

To use them, you first need to make sure that all your toolbars and dock-widgets are given a unique object-name when they are created:

```
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ...
    def initUI(self):               
        ...
        self.toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar(self)
        self.toolbar.setObjectName('foobar')
```

Then you can override `closeEvent` to save the state:

```
    class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        ...
        def closeEvent(self, event):
            with open('/tmp/test.conf', 'wb') as stream:
                stream.write(self.saveState().data())
```

(NB: I've just used a temporary file here for testing, but it would obviously be much better to use something like [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html) in your real application).

Finally, you can restore the state that was saved previously:

```
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.initUI()

        try:
            with open('/tmp/test.conf', 'rb') as stream:
                self.restoreState(QtCore.QByteArray(stream.read()))
        except IOError:
            pass
```

Comment: Your solution is very useful. TA. But I have a little question. By overwriting the `closeEvent()-method` you are about to save the state of the mainwindow in a file. Well, why are you using the `.data()-function?`

Comment: @Sophus. The `saveState` method returns a `QByteArray`. In some versions of python/pyqt, it's possible to write that directly to a file using python - but in others it's not. The `data()` method of a `QByteArray` converts it to a python `bytes` object - which means it's guaranteed to work with all versions of python/pyqt. However, if you use `QSettings` to save the state, you don't have to worry about these compatibility issues because the file-writing is all done by Qt.

Comment: @Sophus. PS: actually, for full compatibility, the `restoreState` method should probably explicitly use a `QByteArray` as well (I've updated my answer accordingly).

Comment: You are the best :) TA :) Well, I have a another question: I know about file mode. In your solution you save (in python word: write) all data as binary, I thought I have to use 'wb' when I want to write a *.jpeg file or something else.

Comment: @Sophus. Not sure what you mean - my example reads and writes bytes and uses the `b` (binary/bytes) mode. The `QByteArray` contains unencoded bytes, not text.